# Unable to fetch all the contact field only of datatype text and Number in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a test case of fetching the contact fields which are of text and number datatype.

If anyone could help here that will be great

Comment: If you facing any problem in your code, please provide the code, this is not the platform to provide a full solution as a code.

Answer (score 0):

```
String ss='Contact';
//fetch all fields in contact object
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Schema.SObjectType leadSchema = schemaMap.get(ss);
List<Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = leadSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values();
List<String> finalList=new List<String>();
for(Schema.SObjectField vv : fieldMap)
{
    finalList.add(vv.getDescribe().getName()+'-'+vv.getDescribe().getLabel());
}
//fetch type of the field
for(String fields : finalList){
    SObjectType r = ((SObject)(Type.forName('Schema.'+ss).newInstance())).getSObjectType();
    DescribeSObjectResult d = r.getDescribe();
    Schema.DisplayType temp=d.fields.getMap().get(fields).getDescribe().getType();
    System.debug(String.valueOf(temp));
}
```

Temp will return type of the field

Comment: well its a bit confusing to understand can you please post it in a better way

Comment: And please tell me how and where to implement it

Comment: Well how can i use it in lightning component??Any suggestions will be kindly appreciated